# ¿Por qué se ejecuta la función al cargar el documento?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo script y se ejecuta al cargar el documento a parte de cuando suceden los eventos.
Si veis que hago mal en ese o cualquier otro sentido se agradece toda aportación.
Gracias :D

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        function comprobar (params) {
            console.log('?');
            $.ajax
            ({
                type:'POST',
                url:'/quizzes/${id}/playAjax/'+$('#respuestaUser').val(),
                success: function(isRight){
                    if (isRight === 'true'){
                        $('#divCorrecto').show(10);
                        $('#divInCorrecto').hide(10);
                    }else{
                        $('#divInCorrecto').show(10);
                        $('#divCorrecto').hide(10);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        $(function(){
            $('#play').on('click', comprobar());

            $('#respuestaUser').on('keypress', e => { if (e.charCode == 13 ){comprobar();}});
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema esta aquí:

```
$('#play').on('click', comprobar());
```

En lugar de asignar *"la función"* que se debe ejecutar cuando se haga clic, estas llamando a la función y asignando el resultado de la misma.

#### Solución:

Simplemente saca los paréntesis, así:

```
$('#play').on('click', comprobar);
```

Comment: Perfecto, ahora funciona bien. :D
No he usado mucho stackoverflow...  ¿tengo que marcar en algún sitio que esta solucionado?
¿esta mal puesto este comentario aquí?

Comment: Hola @E.rick, te aconsejo hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Si la respuesta te fue de ayuda puede votarla y si es la mas acertada, puedes marcarla como tal utilizando el `✔`